# Realm + Swift: When using Realm notifications, is there any way to identify the primary key of the object that was added, deleted or modifed

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have registered a notification handler on a collection as described here

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/react-to-changes/

Per the documentation "This  RealmCollectionChange resolves to an array of index paths that you can pass to a UITableView's batch update methods."

I my use-case, I am not using a UITableView and the indexPaths have no relevance.  Is there any way to use the indexPaths to identify the objects in the collection?

Comment: Show some code to make clear what your problem is and what you want to solve.

Comment: Hi baronfac... Thank you, but as you can see, I was able to obtain a perfectly acceptable solution from the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super good question and we've run into this a lot; wanting to know what *object* was changed, not the objects index. While the Realm observer will present the indexes of the objects that were changed, it doesn't present the object itself per se.

While that's fine if an object is modified as you can look it up from the original result by its index, if it's deleted however, it will no longer exist in the results. Results are live updating and always reflect the underlying data - if it's gone on disk, it's gone in the results.

So here's one option. Suppose there's a tableView with a list of people that can be inserted, modified or deleted.

What this code does is keep a masterList of unmanaged objects which is copy of the actual objects. We make them unmanaged because, per above, Results reflect the underlying managed data - unmanaged results are not affected by those changes.

```
var masterList = List<PersonClass>()

func observePeople() {
    guard let realm = gGetRealm() else { return }

    self.peopleResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self)

    self.personNotificationToken = self.peopleResults.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            for person in strongSelf.peopleResults {
                let unmanagedPerson = PersonClass(value: person)
                strongSelf.masterList.append(unmanagedPerson)
            }

        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            for index in deletions.reversed() {
                let deletedPerson = strongSelf.masterList[index]
                // do something with deletedPerson
                strongSelf.masterList.remove(at: index)
            }
```

I've only included the code for deletions.

When the data is initially loaded, iterate over the results and create unmanaged object copies and store them in a List.

When an object is deleted we know their index and can access the unmanaged person in the masterList, do what we need to with that object and them remove the object so the two lists stay in sync. We .reversed the iteration so the delete from the bottom of the List up to keep the indexes aligned.

There are number of other options as well; when deleting, store the deleted object (copy) in a class var and then do something with that when the deletion event fires. There are even options for key-path observing

Comment: Thank you Jay - this is a good approach.   Seems weird that Realm can't just give us the primaryKey (since they obviously know it), but your approach looks like it will work.

Comment: @wile_e_coyote Give it a try and if it works for you, be sure to accept the answer so it can help others.